# Page works locally and on JSFiddle, but not on server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to work out why my page works locally and on JSFiddle, but not on server. I am not missing any sources.

Page Online: http://bit.ly/1M0f7B7

jsfiddle: http://bit.ly/1MQFlcS

Any ideas??

Comment: Please provide more information and include the relevant code in the question itself. What exactly is not working? What do you expect to happen and what happens? What have you done to debug the problem? Are there any errors? Since JavaScript runs the browser and has nothing to do with the server, most likely there are dependencies that are missing.

Comment: A jsfiddle is a nice addition, but you always have to include the minimal code to reproduce the problem with the question itself.

Comment: It works the same way on both the server and jsfiddle

Comment: the functionality is not the question. i am not sure it is a dependency question because the source of the page works fine and the dependencies shows. i am just not sure because it works locally and on jsfiddle, even though they are the same??

Comment: it's basically a page full of modals, some with text, some with the first image from a google image search based on search terms

Comment: @omer727 i am not sure, but it is not working on mine still.

Answer (score 0):

The script on your page is commented out, just remove the // before it.
Your html file is all in one line which also possibly cause some problems.

Comment: the "commented out" is fixed. but it doesn't work. when i move it to my server it seems to compress the file into 1 line. because as i am working with it locally, it is spread over 90 or so.

Comment: It is still commented out because of the fact that your whole html is in a single line, you just need to add line breaks. The // in your javascript comments out the rest of the line.
This is how your code functions right now:
<valid code>//comment <commented out code>
When you should just move the code after a comment to a new line like so:
<valid code>//comment
<new line of valid code>

Comment: Ok problem solved.

For some reason my notepad++ was putting all of the code on 1 line. 
FYI to change this: Open up the file in Notepad++, choose Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows.

thanks